# Install Chromium Adobe plugins error

Tags: lubuntu, flash, chromium, plugins

While trying to perform simple tasks in Chromium I am experiencing issues with the Adobe Plugin. I cannot view any video because of this. I do not want to use any other browser. When i click "install plugins" , it takes me to the adobe website and it tells that Chromium and Chrome have built in flash players. How should I proceed to attempt to fix this issue?

Comment: what "errors" are you getting when you try and watch Flash things (it works Out Of The Box with Chromium AND Chrome)

Comment: Chromium and Chrome hasn't got built in flash from scratch for Ubuntu, but windows has...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chromium doesn't come with the flash player built in (only chrome). To get started installing Adobe flash player, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open the terminal.  When it opens, run the commands below to enable Ubuntu Partner’s repository. This repo contains important packages that are not installed by default.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

[image]

Finally, run the commands below to install Flash Player Plugin

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`

[image]

Comment: sup guyz,
this is what i've read uptill now. Chrome has built-in flash player but Chromium doesnot. and the adobe website was asuming Chromium as Chrome because it said that you have Chrome web browser and it already has flashplayer installed.
now i will try the above method and hopefully it will work. at the moment, i'm on laptop but as soon as i access my PC, i will try this and report here. thanks again guyz

Comment: @Alamgir Both Chromium and Chrome has built in flash player for Windows. But Ubuntu has never had built in Flash player for Chrome or Chromium.

Comment: @Alvar Chrome comes with a built in flash player (a.k.a pepper flash) even under Ubuntu. But Chromium is stripped out from the pepper flash player and the pdf viewer plugins. Thats why you need to install flash player.

Comment: @Fo2adZz well In Chrome for Ubuntu I've never gotten any flash content to run unless you install an extra flashplugin.

Comment: Thanks @Fo2adZz , i got it installed now. thanks alot :)