# Chromium + Firefox - flash doesn't function w/Pepper.

Tags: firefox, flash, chromium, plugins

Environment:
toshiba chromebook with crouton ubuntu 12.04

Problem:
Flash doesn't function on Chromium.
Flash doesn't function on Firefox.
Sound muted in Ubnutu Desktop.

I'm going to order the following by month, to make the events more clear.

November 2014

- fresh install ubuntu 12.04;
- desktop sound icon has full bars (top right icon near the time and sys settings icon)
- Firefox didn't work with flash.
- Switched to chromium, flash worked. (flash should be packaged w/chromium)

December 2014

- installed Eclipse & JRE 7 (couldn't do 8 on 12.04)
- chromium flash ceased to function
- sound on desktop is null (sound icon shows no bars, cannot adjust in preferences)
- I followed this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure
  It FIXED the sound issue.

January 2015

- I navigated to chrome://plugins -  no flash plugin listed
- On youtube.com page had broken flash image.

steps taken:

- Installed pepper as recommended on other sites, now flash pages (youtube) are 404 completely;
- Uninstalled chromium, reinstall chromium, reinstall pepper
- result == flash still doesn't function
- sound on desktop is muted/disabled

Then I tried this solution from [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283086/install-chromium-adobe-plugins-error) , which unfortunately didn't help.

FIREFOX

- with fresh install: youtube (flash) pages go grey then freeze. Results in "Adobe plug in error."

action: I attempted to install pepper.

result: "failed to load libpepflashplayer.so"

Help please!

Comment: Could you please rewrite the question to a more succinct and sober style? The style of writing would be nice in a different context, but here, it's hard to read this way (Note many here are none-native English speakers)

Comment: yes of course! Sorry about that. I've rewritten the request for help.

Comment: Thanks, much better! I added some spaces to make the layout of your lists work (Needs empty line before; Newline needs two spaces on end of line - see help)

Comment: Oh, but you could still make the question more clear - in the title, and also in the text; You list a history of problems and solutions - but what's the one question here? If it's multiple questions, ask them separate.

Comment: I'll clarify in the title, but I do think the sound/flash issues are intertwined ;)

Comment: As a side note, new youtube videos can play without flash using HTML5 format

Comment: ok thanks. how do I do that, is that a setting?

Comment: The current version of Chromium in Ubuntu 14.04 uses the YouTube HTML5 Player for playing YouTube videos by default. When I was using Ubuntu 12.04, I used to switch to the YouTube HTML5 Player from the [YouTube HTML5 Video Player](https://www.youtube.com/html5) webpage. The YouTube HTML5 Player is the better player to use for playing YouTube videos. I recommend that you try it, because it has better buffering.

Comment: Close voters: It is simply not possible that this question should be labeled as "Unclear what you are asking" considering that Christina has already answered her own question and accepted her answer, so it's certainly not "unclear" to her.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to try an install 14.04 again. 
I tried upgrade, then fresh install via crouton.
Read a few snippets, found that 14.04 was not recommended for my chromebook.

Wiped and fresh install of 12.04  with chromium...sound works.
Even after adding JRE & Eclipse. (which may have been the problem with prior versions)

Thanks for the pointers for this n00b. Much appreciated.

Comment: sure! I just posted to help other people in the same situation. (I'm not sure how to accept answer either.)

Answer (score -2):

Note that adobe does not develop flash player for Linux http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ .

Thus, Your only way is to get **pepper**.

I suggest you getting it with Ubuntu **package managers**. This way updates will be installed **automatically**. As a side bonus, for software to get into official Ubuntu **repository** (kind off online directory from which software is downloaded) it must go through extensive testing, minimizing bugs.

Command line way:

1. Open terminal
   Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Locate the package needed
   Type `sudo apt-cache search pepper | grep plugin`
   You will be prompted for your password. There will be *no* indication, that you are typing something. Just type it and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
   Command breakdown:

   - `sudo` gives you administrative rights
   - `apt-cache search pepper` searches for data about package having `pepper` in its name.
   - `|` pass previous command output to next as argument
   - `grep plugin` filter out all lines not having `plugin`
3. Download the package needed
   Type `sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree`
   The `nonfree` indication means that the **code is not publicly available**, ie, the software is only free as in free beer, not as in free speech.
4. Profit

Gui way (sorry, I'm too lazy to take pictures):

1. Open Launcher
   Press <kbd>super</kbd> key, also known as Windows key.
2. Open **Ubuntu Software Center**
   Typing `Software` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>should be enough
3. Find the package
   Type `pepper` and look for the package that seems the one you need
4. Click install button
5. Profit

Links for further reading:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager
http://www.linuceum.com/Desktop/linuxAppRepos.php
  Note that you **should not** add new repositories, unless you know what you are doing.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool

Comment: step 2 :@localhost:~$ sudo apt-cache search pepper | grep plugin
freshplayerplugin - PPAPI-host NPAPI-plugin adapter
pepflashplugin-installer - Adobe/Google Pepper Flash Player plugin installer

Comment: step 3: (precise)@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package pepperflashplugin-nonfree is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
E: Package 'pepperflashplugin-nonfree' has no installation candidate

Comment: Thanks for both of your suggestions....also, option #2 GUI- it's unavail in software center for me.

Comment: Open Ubuntu software center. Go to Edit -> Software Sources. Is multiverse ticked?

Comment: yes multiverse is checked

Comment: Try these steps https://sites.google.com/site/installationubuntu/tools/pepper-flash-ppa-for-chromium